# Is there a way to apply -WFormat Security to a function that is taking a string literal?

Tags: c++

I have a `log()` function that takes a `std::string`, then hands it off to a call to `snprintf()`, eg:

```cpp
template<typename... TArgs>
void log(const std::string& str, TArgs... args) {
  char buffer[8192];
  snprintf(buffer, 8192, format.c_str(), args...);
  // do some stuff
}
```

Using this function raises a warning (**-WFormat-security**) as we're not passing in a string literal to `snprintf()` (which makes sense). However, everywhere `log()` is called, it's passed a string literal. Is there a way to let the compiler know we want to get the warning for `log()` itself (if a literal is not passed in) and not the inner call to `snprintf()`?

The code compiles with GCC under Ubuntu.

Comment: If every call to `log()` receives a string literal, then why are you using `std::string` instead of `const char*` (or even `const char(&)[N]` where `N` is a template parameter)?

Comment: Ditch the C++ and `va_arg`s with `vsnprintf` and `__attribute__((__printf__`

Comment: Not with `std::string`. I once made it work (in the early C++11 days, so things may have changed for the worse or for the better) with a custom class though. Beware, it will involved some nasty `constexpr` magic, and likely some lambdas and even a macro or two.

Comment: In particularly, note that C++-style variadics are your *enemy* here, you need the actual C-style-variadics call to be able to see the string literal. Thus the need for a local class with a constexpr member.